# Where to initialize my classes codename one

Tags: java, class, codenameone

My question is simple, however I'm so new to codename one, I have no clue. I have a working series of classes in my project, there is a main class that initializes the others. I have an interface designed using codename one, however I don't know where to initialize my main class, i.e., invoke the builder of the class.

I've tried several things, however when I run the application, the simulator just gets all grey and nothing happens.

Help really appreciated!

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project in Codename One you specify a package, this is crucial since changing that package later is a bit hard. All native mobile apps rely on something similar to a package so Codename One uses this to identify your app.

Within this package is the main class baring the name of your application. It has 4 methods by default `init(Object)`, `start`, `stop`, `destroy`. For a GUI builder application you also have the `initVars(Resources)` method in the `Statemachine` class.

So generally use the `init` methods.

Comment: I tried to initialize it here: protected void initVars(Resources res){
  Bedroom zona1 = new Bedroom("Zona1");
 }         however when I try to something like zona1.method() in a button action, it gives me a nullpointer exception. I checked and there is a warning that says that zona1 is not being used.

Comment: You defined zona in the method rather than the class.

Comment: How should I define it for the class?

Comment: private Bedroom zona1;
public void initVars(Resources res){ 
   zona1 = new Bedroom("Zona1"); }

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Plus, I'm not sure if you are the creator of codename one, but I know you had a lot to do with it, great work!